# Laravel 8 uploading "folder" using webkitdirectory and Storage

Tags: php, laravel

Upon checking the Laravel 8 Documentation, it seems like there is no method (not that I'm aware of) for uploading folders (yep, not file) and storing them in `Storage`'s public disk.

I might be looking at the documentation of `File Storage` for the wrong approach.

Is there a practice for uploading folders (with files inside the said folder) in the `Storage`?